# Не работают команды node *, gulp, но и не пишет что нет таких команд

Tags: node.js, gulp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
npm команды работают. Сижу с общественного wifi, может быть из-за этого не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы набирает node (если он установлен), вы попадаете в интерактивную консоль node `>` и приглашение для ввода команд. У вас же похоже на [Microsoft HPC Pack Command Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc972841(v=ws.11).aspx). И "ваш node" совсем не Node, а команда [node](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947691(v=ws.11).aspx) из этого пакета.

Для определения версии Node.js выполнить:

```
node --version
node -v
```

Выполнить какой либо скрипт (и это должно работать)

```
node script.js
```

а в script.js, например:

```
console.log('node.js')
```

Comment: У меня node был установлен 100%, не смотря на это, я установил еще раз, при этом ошибка та же, команды пробовал всякие разные, все равно выдает то что на скрине

Comment: я раньше просто запускал команду gulp и она работала, как сейчас запускать ? Получается, это связано с тем, что я установил microsoft HPC ?

Comment: да, имена приложений совпадают.